# Preposition problem of 'on'

Tags: prepositions

In one our Indian English literature textbook, one of the objective was given as follows-

*Students will use vocabulary to write about a **range general** vocational subject area.*

Is the sentence correct? Shouldn't we use **"range on general"**?

Comment: No, neither is correct. It should be "a range **of**".

Comment: To *mainstream* Anglophones, @DanielRoseman's interpretation (and hence "correction") is probably the natural choice. But even though I'm not that familiar with "Indian English" myself, I rather suspect that's ***not*** the intended meaning of the text. I think probably the writer should have ***included a hyphen***, because the intention is to explicitly contrast ***range-general*** subject areas from ***range-specific*** (cf ***domain-specific***) subjects. But maybe we should seek confirmation from actual experts in IE. But "range-general, domain-general", etc., are not established usages.